# Distance measure for categorical attributes for k-Nearest Neighbor

Tags: classification, distance-functions, k-nearest-neighbour, euclidean

For my class project, I am working on the [Kaggle competition - Don't get kicked](https://www.kaggle.com/c/DontGetKicked)

The project is to classify test data as good/bad buy for cars. There are 34 features and the data is highly skewed. I made the following choices:

1. Since the data is highly skewed, out of 73,000 instances, 64,000 instances are bad buy and only 9,000 instances are good buy. Since building a decision tree would overfit the data, I chose to use kNN - K nearest neighbors.
   After trying out kNN, I plan to [try out Perceptron and SVM techniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60270/categorizing-transportation-modes-with-k-nearest-neighbor), if kNN doesn't yield good results. Is my understanding about overfitting correct?
2. Since some features are numeric, I can directly use the Euclid distance as a measure, but there are other attributes which are categorical. To aptly use these features, I need to come up with my own distance measure. I read about [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), but I am still unclear on how to merge 2 distance measures so that each feature gets equal weight.
3. Is there a way to find a good approximate for value of k? I understand that this depends a lot on the use-case and varies per problem. But, if I am taking a simple vote from each neighbor, how much should I set the value of k? I'm currently trying out various values, such as 2,3,10 etc.

I researched around and found these links, but these are not specifically helpful -
a) [Metric for nearest neighbor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72871/metric-for-nearest-neighbor-method), which says that finding out your own distance measure is equivalent to 'kernelizing', but couldn't make much sense from it.
b) [Distance independent approximation of kNN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39139/distance-independent-approximation-of-nearest-neighbor-k-nn) talks about R-trees, M-trees etc. which I believe don't apply to my case.
c) [Finding nearest neighbors using Jaccard coeff](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/finding-nearest-neighbors-using-jaccard-distance-for-positive-real-valued-vecto?newreg=9ae97574fe1c4f57ab198e9e3711dc5a)

Comment: Avoid [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) on SE. You have the same question on [SciComp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/distance-measure-for-categorical-attributes-for-k-nearest-neighbor).